# Preview multiple images right after selection with stimulus javascript (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, stimulusjs

I am dealing with a rails project where I am trying to upload multiple images and have them previewed right after image selection. I am using stimulus, ruby on rails, js6

The HTML is a form used to create a new product - I am also using cloudinary - to upload multiple pictures and simpleformfor

app/views/products/_form.html.erb

```html
<%= simple_form_for product do |m| %>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" data-controller="upload">
        <%= m.input :photos, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'hidden', id: 'photo-input',
        data: {action: 'change->upload#displayPreview'} },
        label_html: { class: 'upload-photo'}, label: ':camera: Upload a photo' %>
        <% if @product.photos.attached? %>
            <% @product.photos.each do |photo| %>
              <%= cl_image_tag photo.key, height: 100, width: 200, crop: :fill, data: { target: 'upload.image'} %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<%= m.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

the HTML form code for 1 image is as follow

```html
<div data-controller="upload">
<label class="file optional upload-photo" for="photo-input">Upload photo</label>
  <input class="form-control-file file optional hidden" id="photo-input" data-action="change->upload#displayPreview" type="file" name="product[photos][]">
        <%= cl_image_tag "", height: 100, width: 200, crop: :fill, data: { 'upload-target': 'image',  'upload-index-value': 0 } %>
</div>
</div>
```

The code for 1 image is as follow and working fine if the form was just for 1 image, but how would i transform the following code to accommodate for multiple image uploading?
I tried several things using for loops and this.imageTargets.forEach((element) => {.. and even indexes but at no avail..

javascript/controllers/upload_controller.js

```js
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['image']
  displayPreview(event) {
    const input = event.target
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        this.imageTarget.src = event.currentTarget.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0])
      this.imageTarget.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate your comments and alternative solutions..

Answer (score 1):

For file fields with multiple images, you need to use the for loop in your JS which will detect the input files length. For your reference you can update your js as like.

image_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["input"]

    preview() {
        var input = this.inputTarget
        var files = input.files
        var imgLoc = document.getElementById("Img")
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function() {
                let image = document.createElement("img")
                imgLoc.appendChild(image)
                image.style.height = '100px'
                image.src = reader.result
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i])
        }
    }
}
```

As you are displaying the output by replacing the preview.png, for this you don't need the image preview. This will create images.

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="mb-3" data-controller="image" id = "Img">
    <%=f.label :images, class: "form-label"  %>
    <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, class: "form-control", accept: "image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg", "data-image-target": "input", "data-action": "image#preview" %>
</div>
```